# Se lever de bonne heure, qu'est-ce que l'heure a de bonne ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Existe-t-il un sens que j'ignore au mot *bon(ne)* qui signifierait *tôt* ou quelque chose du genre ? Je doute que l'expression

> Se lever de bonne heure.

ait comme signification

> Se lever à la bonne heure.

Qu'en est-il ?

Comment: Voyons, c'est une question de bon sens ;-)

Comment: Haha, elle est bonne !

Comment: Je crois que la bonne heure pour savoir quelle heure est désignée par _de bonne heure_, c'est une bonne heure avant l'heure à laquelle tu désires te lever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On peut bien sûr très bien dire que **se lever de bonne heure** (expression où *de bonne heure* veut dire « tôt ») c'est **se lever à la bonne heure** (ici l'adjectif *bon* voulant dire « qui convient »), mais l'usage distingue les deux en tant qu'expressions, même si parfois les deux usages sont confondus.

**De bonne heure** (attesté en 1458<sup>1</sup>) veut dire à une heure matinale, tôt (Proust, *À la recherche du temps perdu* : « *Longtemps je me suis couché de bonne heure* ». Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* fait rentrer cet usage de *bon* dans le « domaine temporel » avec une valeur intensive. Je connais au moins une variante régionale (mon sud-ouest natal : à *bonne heure*).

**À la bonne heure** (attesté en 1450<sup>2</sup>) est une locution adverbiale qui peut signifier *au bon moment*, *à propos*, ou marquer l'approbation (Molière, l'*Avare* : 
« *Si tu avais senti quelque inclination pour elle, à la bonne heure, je te l’aurais fait épouser, au lieu de moi ; mais cela n’étant pas, je suivrai mon premier dessein, et je l’épouserai moi-même*. »
Je l'utilise moi-même pour signifier « ouf ! » (soulagement, dans le sens de « enfin » ), je pensais que c'était un méridionalisme, mais je viens juste de trouver une occurrence de l'expression avec ce sens là, dans *Les Plaideurs* de Racine : « *Je ne dormirai point. — Hé bien ! à la bonne heure ! Qu’on ne le quitte pas.* »

<sup>1</sup> : *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* sld Alain Rey, éditions Le Robert
<sup>2</sup> : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey, éditions Le Robert

Answer (score 2):

Une petite note, histoire de compléter la réponse de Laure : **se lever tôt** est souvent associé à une bonne habitude dans la langue française, comme en atteste une autre expression :

> L'avenir appartient à ceux qui **se lèvent tôt**.

Cela expliquerait entre autres l'association existante entre l'expression « de bonne heure » et « tôt ».

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec "il va falloir qu'il se lève de bonne heure" a aussi un sens "douter de la possibilité sans un effort important."

Comment: [Pas qu'au Québec](https://jaimelesmots.com/devoir-se-lever-de-bonne-heure-falloir-se-lever-de-bonne-heure-ou-pouvoir-se-lever-de-bonne-heure).